# Passing form fields to python via ajax and handling the return

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to resolve the issues I have with passing values from a form to javascript.

Here is the code. The python script works seamlessly and will given the form values return a string every time.

```
<head>
    <title>Line Chart</title>
    <script>
        function clickme() {
        putgraph();
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function alertbox() {
                alert(ajaxResponse);
        }
    </script>
    <script src="Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
                    function drawgraph(z) {
                            var v = document.getElementById("frmvar");
                            v.value = z;
                            return draw();
                    };
                    function draw() {
                            var ajaxResponse=null;
                            $.ajax({
                            url: "/currentcost.py",
                            data: $("form[name='frm']").serialize(),
                            success: function(response){
                                    ajaxResponse=response;
                                    }, async: false
                            });
                    return ajaxResponse;
                    }
    </script>
    <script>
    function putgraph()
            {
            tg=drawgraph("t");
            alert(tg);
                    var lineChartData = {
                            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
                            datasets : [
                                    {
                                            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                                            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                                            data : [tg]
                                            // data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
                                    },
                            ]
                    }

                    var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
            }
    </script>

    <meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no">
    <style>
            canvas{
            }
    </style>
</head>
```

Here is what happens:

When a user is done with the form they click the button which submits it – runs the function `clickme` at the top. That runs `putgraph` which is where I think it's going wrong.

The alert window in `putgraph` displays `"undefined"` which suggests to me the `putgraph` function starts before the `drawgraph` finishes despite all the AJAX callback stuff being in place, and working before I put it all together!

I know Javascript is asynchronous but I thought the `drawgraph` and `draw` functions had 'overcome' that issue by using the callback handler.

Would really appreciate some eyes on this looking at what I'm doing wrong and better still suggesting ways to put it right.

UPDATE:

Thanks to all who answered. I've edited the script above with the answer I used. I found the async keyword REALLY useful as it did away with all the messy callback procedures. HTH's anyone else :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call functions like that *inside* your callback, not *after* your callback.

If your callback does nothing but "variable = value" then there's no guarantee that variable will be set when you just call the other function.

e: furthermore, your drawgraph doesn't return anything, so even if your method did work, you're never passing the data back.

Answer (score 0):

as Collin said your "drawgraph" returns nothing, as it only calls "draw()". You have a callback function called "handleResource()": For debugging try to add an "alert()" call there, this should produce a response.

To go deeper please understand that "draw()" will exit *immediately* and the "$.ajax()" call will run in parallel (think of it like a "thread"). So the only valid exit point in your example is "function handleResource(response)" (called in the "success:" function).

You can try the following (not tested):

```
    function drawgraph(z, callback) {
            var v = document.getElementById("frmvar");
            v.value = z;
            function handleResponse(response) {
                    ajaxResponse = response;
                    callback(response); // this will call a function given as parameter to "drawgraph"
            }
            draw(handleResponse);
    };
```

And then change the call to:

```
    tg=drawgraph("t", function (response) {
      alert(response);
    });
```

This should produce an alert box containing the "response".

HTH,